Trying to fetch tweets using twitter API and get 453
I bought the Basic plan of X, and I tried this code:
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

# Authenticate to Twitter API (I put the details when running my code)
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# Define search query
query = 'dog'

# Define date range (replace 'since_date' and 'until_date' with desired dates)
since_date = '2024-01-01'
until_date = '2024-01-02'

# Fetch tweets
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=query, lang='en', since=since_date, until=until_date).items()

# Store tweets in a file
with open('tweets.json', 'w') as f:
    for tweet in tweets:
        f.write(tweet._json + '\n')

and get the following error:

Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

what should I do?

"what should I do?" Use Tweepy.Client to call the V2 API. The error says you have "access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints" which in the Basic tier includes the "recent" search but not the "full history search" and "limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only" which doesn't include searching for tweets via the v1.1 API.
